# Amazon product API capabilities (user reviews)

Tags: api, amazon-web-services

just one questions.

Amazon offers product API to retrieve products information

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/USSortValuesArticle.html#USSortValuesArticle_books

you can retrieve price, salesrank, reviewrank, etc. But it looks like there is no API where you can retrieve **customers reviews** for a certain product.

does anybody know if there is a way that you can retrieve customer reviews of a certain product using amazon API?

i have researched that Amazon offers "Product Advertising API" program, where you can access to more information like user reviews, but I am not sure you can retrieve it and store on variables like I could do with AWS ValuesArticles.

thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can't, I can see that the Product Advertising API returns a URL to a page (for embedding in an IFRAME) containing the URLs, but you can't retrieve the reviews themselves.

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/RG_Reviews.html